# Tuple to HList using productElements

Tags: shapeless

I am using Shapeless 2.2.5. 
I try to convert a tuple to HList using the code below.

```
 import shapeless._
import syntax.std.product._

(23, "foo", 2.0, true).productElements
```

But I get a compilation error.

```
[error] /scala/testScala/src/test/scala/lombok/shapeless/TestTuple2HList.scala:12: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[(Int, String, Double, Boolean)]
[error]      (23, "foo", 2.0, true).productElements
```

The test conversions.scala in
https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/conversions.scala

did not provide an implicit value for Generic[(Int,String,Double,Boolean)].

Have I missed some imports ?

Thanks in advance for any assistance !

Shing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `import syntax.std.tuple._` rather than `import syntax.std.product._`.

Comment: I still have the same error with:  import shapeless._
  import syntax.std.tuple._

Comment: What Scala version are you using?

Comment: Silly me ! I was using Scala 2.10. It works after I switched to Scala 2.11.  Thanks!