# retain key information in implicit LabelledGeneric

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have this code that convert an arbitrary size of class to an HList

```
class Record[H <: HList](val hs: H)

object Record {
  import shapeless.LabelledGeneric
  def apply[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L]) = new Record[L](gen.to(p))
}
```

I would like to use it as follows:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.singleton._
val h = Record('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2)
@ h.hs
res91: cmd90.<refinement>.this.type.Out = 1 :: 2 :: HNil
```

However the keys are not retained after the conversion. As opposed to creating the same HList:

```
@ h.hs.keys //error: could not find implicit value for parameter keys: shapeless.ops.record.Keys[this.Out]
@ ('a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil).keys //works ok
```

The question is how to retain the key information in the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use records incorrectly.

Things like `'a ->> 1`, `'b ->> 2` shouldn't be used separately, they should be used inside `HList`s like `'a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil`.

When you write `Record('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2)` the argument of `Record` is considered as `Tuple2`. Since `Tuple2` is a case class, `LabelledGeneric` transforms it implicitly into an `HList` (actually, a shapeless' record). Look at your `h`, its type is very strange (pseudocode):

```
Record['_1 -> 'a -> Int :: '_2 -> 'b -> Int :: HNil]
```

(`_1` and `_2` are field names of `Tuple2`).

So how to fix your code depends on what you really wanted to get (I'm not sure). One possible way is

```
//  class Record[H <: HList](val hs: H)

object Record {
  def apply[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L]) = /*new Record[L](*/gen.to(p)/*)*/
}

case class MyCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int)

val h = Record(MyCaseClass(1, 2))

h/*.hs*/   // 1 :: 2 :: HNil

h/*.hs*/.keys   // 'a :: 'b :: HNil

('a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil).keys   // 'a :: 'b :: HNil
```

---

> I would like to have something like `Record('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2)` ... or potentially `Record(('a', 1), ('b', 2))`
>   as an input, and an HList `'a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil` as an output.

Then you don't need `LabelledGeneric`. You can transform `Record('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2)` into just a tuple `('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2)` (it's `Record.unapply(...).get` if you defined `case class Record(p: Product)`) and then this [tuple into HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258391/tuple-to-hlist-using-productelements):

```
import shapeless.{::, HNil}
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2).productElements == 'a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, makes sense. Ultimately I'm looking for a way to construct an hlist with keys, where I won't have to specify the case class beforehand.

Comment: @jamborta `'a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil` is "a way to construct an hlist with keys, where I won't have to specify the case class beforehand". If you want something else please specify. Maybe you can write some input and desirable output.

Comment: I would like to have something like `Record('a ->> 1, 'b ->> 2) ` (which you said it wouldn't work) or potentially `Record(('a', 1), ('b', 2))` as an input, and an `HList` `'a ->> 1 :: 'b ->> 2 :: HNil` as an output.

Comment: @jamborta Ok, it's easy, I updated my answer, check if this works for you.