# Unzip a query of tuple in Slick+shapeless

Tags: scala, slick, shapeless

I have a Slick (grouping) query returning a tuple of integers which should be then combined using one of SQL aggregation functions. The size of the tuple is not dynamic but I would like to be able to define it in a single place with possibility to change it later. I use shapeless elsewhere in my project so it is natural to use it here as well.

So, let's say we have a tuple type `type Agg = (Rep[Int], Rep[Int], Rep[Int])` and a query with type `Query[Agg, _, Seq]`

I can then define poly's for aggregation like this:

```
object sum extends (Query[Rep[Int], Int, Seq] -> Rep[Int])(_.sum.getOrElse(0))
object sumAgg extends(Query[Agg, _, Seq] -> Agg)(q => (q.map(_._1), q.map(_._2), q.map(_._3)).map(sum))
```

But I can't find a way to get rid of explicit tuple unzipping in sumAgg poly. How can I transform a Query of tuple of Int's (aka Agg) into a tuple of queries of Int's?

Let's even simplify this. Supposing I have

```
val hlist = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil
val tuple = (4, 5, 6)
hlist.zipWithIndex.map(m)
```

What would be the definition of m to produce, say, a hlist of `(1*4) :: (2*5) :: (3*6) :: HNil`? I know I could directly zip hlist with tuple but in this scenario I think I do need to pick tuple elements one by one by their positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `sumAgg` with type classes.

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, Nat, Poly1, Succ}
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.poly.->
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Tupler
import shapeless.ops.tuple.{At, Length, Mapper}
import slick.lifted.{Query, Rep, Shape}
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

trait MkHList[Agg <: Product, N <: Nat] {
  type Out <: HList
  def apply(q: Query[Agg, _, Seq]): Out
}
object MkHList {
  type Aux[Agg <: Product, N <: Nat, Out0 <: HList] = MkHList[Agg, N] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[Agg <: Product, N <: Nat, Out0 <: HList](f: Query[Agg, _, Seq] => Out0): Aux[Agg, N, Out0] = new MkHList[Agg, N] {
    override type Out = Out0
    override def apply(q: Query[Agg, _, Seq]): Out = f(q)
  }

  implicit def zero[Agg <: Product]: Aux[Agg, _0, HNil] = instance(_ => HNil)
  implicit def succ[Agg <: Product, N <: Nat, A](implicit
    tailMkHList: MkHList[Agg, N],
    at: At.Aux[Agg, N, Rep[A]],
    shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, Rep[A], A, Rep[A]]
  ): Aux[Agg, Succ[N], Query[Rep[A], A, Seq] :: tailMkHList.Out] =
    instance(q => q.map(_.at[N]) :: tailMkHList(q))
}

trait SumAgg[Agg <: Product] {
  def apply(q: Query[Agg, _, Seq]): Agg
}
object SumAgg {
  implicit def mkSumAgg[Agg <: Product, N <: Nat, L <: HList, Tpl <: Product](implicit
    length: Length.Aux[Agg, N],
    mkHList: MkHList.Aux[Agg, N, L],
    tupler: Tupler.Aux[L, Tpl],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[Tpl, sum.type, Agg]
  ): SumAgg[Agg] = q => tupler(mkHList(q)).map(sum)
}

def sumAgg[Agg <: Product](q: Query[Agg, _, Seq])(implicit sumAggInst: SumAgg[Agg]): Agg = sumAggInst(q)

type Agg = (Rep[Int], Rep[Int], Rep[Int])
sumAgg(??? : Query[Agg, _, Seq]): Agg
```

Comment: The problem is, object sumAgg is transformed in the caller to Agg, whereas case class sumAgg remains a sumAgg. Therefore I do not yet understand how to adapt this code to be able to use it as a replacement for the old object-based Poly.

Comment: Right. Now it compiles and works. The only minor thing that remains for me to do is try and understand how. :) Thanks, @Dmytro, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering your simplified version:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.tuple._  // brings implicits for tuple.productElements

// defines your polymorphic mapper

object MulPoly extends Poly1 {
  // you're going to need one case for each pair of types that you might face.
  // E.g. (Int, Int), (Int, String), (String, String), etc.
  implicit val intPairCase: Case.Aux[(Int, Int), Int] = at({ case (a, b) => a * b })
}

val hlist = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil
val tuple = (4, 5, 6)
val tupleHList = tuple.productElements
>>> tupleHList: Int :: Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil = 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: HNil

hlist
    .zip(tupleHList)  // intermediate result here: (1, 4) :: (2, 5) :: (3, 6) :: HNil
    .map(MulPoly)     // map MulPoly over the HList
>>> res0: Int :: Int :: Int :: shapeless.HNil = 4 :: 10 :: 18 :: HNil
```

So, essentially, your `m` is a `Poly1`, that can map on 2-tuples of types that constitute your hlist and a tuple.

You might want to consult with [Type Astronaut's Guide to Shapeless, Section 7](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:poly) about ploymorphic mapping, and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258391/tuple-to-hlist-using-productelements) about how to get an hlist out of any tuple.

Comment: Thanks but I specifically wanted to understand how to use Nat's (produced by zipWithIndex) in a Poly used in subsequent map. Like I said, direct zip between HList and a tuple seems to be okay in this simplified scenario but it is not applicable in the original situation.